# URLTrigger plugin. Need examples for TXT-RegEx or XML-XPath

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So, I try to use plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin.

I want to trigger my Jenkins job when the text "Last build (#40), 17 hr ago" in the response of provided URL is changed (build number will be different after each build).

So I made following configurations: 
1. Build trigger: Set [URLTrigger] - Poll with a URL. 
2. Specified URL to another Jenkins: http://mydomain:8080/job/MasterJobDoNothing/ 
3. Set Inspect URL content option 
4. Set Monitor the contents of a TEXT response 
5. Set following regular expression: ^Last build[.]* 
6. Set Schedule every minute: * * * * *  
7. Trigger the job on another Jenkins

Actual result: My job wasn't triggered.

Then I tried to deal with XML/XPath and specify 
8. Set Monitor the contents of an XML response 
9. Set XPath: //*[@id="side-panel"] (also tried with one "/")

Actual result: the same.

Tell me please what I'm doing wrong? Please provide examples of RegEx or XPath if possible.
Thanks, Dima

Answer (score 1):

I managed to trigger reliably with regex setting.

- The regex pattern matches each line of the input.
- No need to use ^ or $. it always match line start to line end.
- This plugin compares the contents of the matched lines. It triggers if different.
- This plugin compares the count of the matched lines. It triggers if the count is different.
- This plugin uses matches() method of java.util.regex.Matcher. So the regex pattern should conform to it. (it's fairly normal regex)

As for your example,

> Last build.*

may work.

Refs:

- Reference of regex patten:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
- Reference of Matcher: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()
- The regex trigger source code:
  github.com/jenkinsci/urltrigger-plugin/blame/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/urltrigger/content/TEXTContentType.java

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the "RSS for all" link as a trigger URL instead, and `/feed/entry[1]` as the XPath expression for the XML response content nature.

PS: I was using [PathEnq](http://www.qutoric.com/xslt/analyser/xpathtool.html) to debug the XPath expression.